# Unable to add ListViewItem - Windows universal app C++

Tags: c++, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm writing a windows universal app (store app) in C++ and XAML, and I made a listview which I want to add items to. This works perfectly fine when hard-coding the items, but once I want to add them via a loop, this doesn't work anymore. And I get the error

```
cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'Platform::Object ^'
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

My code:

```
/* This works */
myListView->Items->Append("Hello, world!");

/* This doesn't work */
const char* strarray[] = { "Hello", "World", "Awesome" };
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(strarray); i++) {
    myListView->Items->Append(strarray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a basic datatype for your string array

```
const char* strarray[]
```

So maybe the function `xxx->Items->Append()` needs to receive a managed datatype which would be the following for example:

```
array<String^>^ strarray = { "Hello", "World", "Awesome" };
```

Comment: While the compiler doesn't complain about the data type anymore when using `Array<String^>^`, I'm unable to retrieve any data from the array as it just returns the string `Windows.Foundation.IReferenceArray1<String>`

Comment: Can you give me any example what you are trying to do in your code. If you just want to add the array to your `myListView` then your could replace for whole for loop with the following line: `myListView->Items->AddRange(strarray);`.

Comment: Sadly didn't work, the compiler gives me this error: `ItemCollection has no member AddRange`

Comment: Okay I see then you have to add manually the objects with the `Add()` method. Therefore I suggest something like this `for each(String^ str in strarray){ myListView->Items->Add(str); }`. So you don't need the index `i`.